# Can you use floats for Time in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, time

Say I want to use increments of time smaller than 1 second. Should I use something like 0.25, or would it be better to just use milliseconds? Also, just to clarify, the default measurement of time in Ruby is seconds, isn't it? So if I used 30 as a variable, it would interpret it as 30 seconds and not 30 minutes, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `Time` class within Ruby has a `usec` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html#method-i-usec), which gets the milliseconds within a Time object, so you can go finer grained than a second within Ruby's Time objects.

If you used 30 as a variable, it would indeed count that as seconds:

```
irb(main):001:0> time = Time.now
=> 2014-03-12 14:13:44 +1100
irb(main):002:0> time + 1
=> 2014-03-12 14:13:45 +1100
```